# How to create a process tree?

Tags: linux, command-line, process, command

I have some code that kills processes and their children/grandchildren. I want to test this code.

Currently I'm doing `$ watch date > date.txt`, which creates a process with a child.

Is there any way to create a **parent -> child -> grandchild** tree? What  command can make that happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
#This is a process with an id of $$

( sleep 1000 )&               #this creates an idle child
( (sleep 1000)& sleep 1000 )& #this creates an idle child and grandchild
wait                          #this waits for direct children to finish
```

Running the above as `./1.sh &` on my system created the following process tree:

```
$ command ps -o pid,ppid,pgrp,stat,args,wchan --forest
  PID  PPID  PGRP STAT COMMAND                     WCHAN
24949  4783 24949 Ss   /bin/bash                   wait
25153 24949 25153 S     \_ /bin/sh ./1.sh          sigsuspend
25155 25153 25153 S     |   \_ sleep 1000          hrtimer_nanosleep
25156 25153 25153 S     |   \_ sleep 1000          hrtimer_nanosleep
25158 25156 25153 S     |       \_ sleep 1000      hrtimer_nanosleep
```

You can notice that the tree has the same process group (**PGRP**) of 25153, which is identical to the **PID** of the first process.
The shell creates a process group whenever you start a new command in interactive mode (or with job control explicitly turned on).

The **PGRP** mechanism allows the shell to send a signal to the whole process group at once without creating a race condition. This is used for job control, and when your script runs and a foreground job, for sending:

- (SIG)**INTR**  when the user presses C-C
- (SIG)**QUIT**  when the user presses C-\
- (SIG)**STP** when the user presses C-Z

You can do the same by doing, for example:

```
kill -INTR -25153
```

where **INTR** is the signal and 25153 is the process group you want to send the signal to. The `-` before the 25153 means you're targeting a **PGRP** id rather than a **PID**.

In your case, the signal you should be sending is `-TERM` (request termination). Term is the default signal `kill` sends, however, you have to specify it explicitly if you're targeting a group rather than a **PID**.

```
kill -TERM -25153
```

If you want to kill the process group of the last background job you started, you can do:

```
kill -TERM -$!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for. Your explanation is going to be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Add a shell call

```
sh -c "watch date > date.txt"
```

For more levels, add more shells around

Answer (score 1):

You can create a recursive script. eg in file `/tmp/run`

```
#!/bin/bash
depth=${1:-3}
f(){
 let depth--
 if [ $depth -gt 0 ]
 then $0 $depth
 else sleep 999
 fi
}
f
```

then `chmod +x /tmp/run` and do `/tmp/run 3`.

Answer (score 0):

The `ps` command on freebsd doesn't seem to be able to produce a process tree. Fortunately there is a package called `pstree` which contains a program that will do precisely that.